# Pass_band filter in Python

Tags: python, audio, scipy, filtering, pydub

I've develop a script that given an input file, extract the voice signal and give in output the signal WITHOUT voice (so the signal that containts the noise):

```
!pip install pydub
from pydub import AudioSegment
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
audio = AudioSegment.from_file('fileInput.mp3')
```

[Download fileInput.mp3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Imh-YT76LGrbrl-w4DOG_611DTMZveE1/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

```
samples = audio.get_array_of_samples()
plt.plot(list(samples))
```

[image]

```
from scipy import signal
sos = signal.butter(10, [100, 4000], 'bandstop', fs=44100, output='sos')

filtered = signal.sosfilt(sos, np.array(samples))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(np.array(samples))
plt.plot(filtered)

plt.title('After 1 - 10 Hz pass-band filter')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

To export the file filtered (so the file that contains the noise) i write that following line:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

write('./test.wav', 44100, filtered.astype(np.int16))
```

That codes save a file **but** the file don't have the same lenght of the original (input) one.
[image]

As you can notice, the input file has 36second lenght instead the output is 1:12 ...

[Download Output file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMbMjrYdS1bAu1UaV5clUJCBRBqGFOeN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: there are a couple points where this could have gone wrong and without more info about the test file i can only guess. firstly the sample_rate is crucial. what is the sample_rate of the input file? you specify later its 441000. thats probably a typo and should be 44100. but it has to match what the test file is. also pydub imports multi channel audio seqentialy. thats probably not what you want for filtering or saving later. if you specify all the properties of the test file, i can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: @ruff09 you can download the input file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Imh-YT76LGrbrl-w4DOG_611DTMZveE1/view?usp=sharing
As you can see from the file (recorded by me), there are noises and my voice. The goal is to ELIMINATE my voice (for privacy issues) and output an mp3 file containing ONLY the noises.

Also yes, correcting 441000 to 44100 the problem remains.
I've updated the codes

Comment: @ruff09 You can download the output file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMbMjrYdS1bAu1UaV5clUJCBRBqGFOeN/view?usp=sharing 
the result looks good but it is strange that it has a different length to the input file

Comment: The original is ~36 seconds, and your output file is ~72 seconds.  The original is stereo; I suspect your processing has resulted in the stereo data being treating as a mono signal that is twice as long as the original; see @ruff09's comment about how pydub handles mult-channel audio.

Answer (score 1):

The input file is stereo. The pydub documentation states that:

> AudioSegment(…).get_array_of_samples()
> Returns the raw audio data as an array of (numeric) samples. Note: if the audio has multiple channels, the samples for each channel will be serialized – for example, stereo audio would look like [sample_1_L, sample_1_R, sample_2_L, sample_2_R, …]

for scipy this is just 1 "long" channel. it can not know that the samples are split like this. A filter also has state. Meaning it can not process data that is shuffled like this and produce the desired output.

either you reshape the data from AudioSegment for example into 2 mono channels like:

```
[sample1L, sample2L, ...]
```

and

```
[sample1R, sample2R, ...]
```

and process these individually.

**OR**

you simply convert the AudioSegment to mono. like so:

```
audio = AudioSegment.from_file('fileInput.mp3')
audio = audio.set_channels(1)
```

either way I highly recommend you use the sample rate of the input file, wherever a sample rate is required. else loading a file with other sample rate will shift the filter frequencies and change the length and playback speed of the output file. e.g.

```
sos = signal.butter(10, [100, 4000], 'bandstop', fs=audio.frame_rate, output='sos')
```